# Помогите расставить запятые в предложении: Да я слышала и так и так говорят

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите расставить запятые в предложении. Нужна ли запятая после "слышала", и нужно ли разделить запятой "и так и так"?

- Свет, как правильно: Иран или Ирак?
- Да я слышала и так и так говорят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом примере если строго, то надо кавычки:
*Свет, как правильно (говорить): "республика Иран" или "республика Ирак"?

Как правильно говорить: "хурма" или "королёк"?*
Но:
*Что больше: Иран или Ирак?*

А второй:
*Да я слышала, (что) и так и так говорят.* || Пропуск союза запятую не отменяет.
https://logoprav.ru/russkij-yazyk/itak